# Finding continuous subsequence in Lebesgue Bochner space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Assume you have a sequence $x_n(t)$ in $L^p(0,T;X)$ $1<p<\infty$, where $X$ is Banach.

Under which conditions or in which special case can one extract a subsequence that is continuous in $t$ wrt. the norm in $X$ ?

Comment: Without further information, this is impossible to answer. If your are looking for embedding theorems, then you need e.g., information of time derivative of $x_n$'s.